# Use wp_upload_dir() correctly

Tags: plugins, uploads

All,
I'm using the Uploadify plugin to upload some images. I've included the uploadify folder in my themes folder. However, when I try and call uploadify.php I get the following error:

Call to undefined function wp_upload_dir()

My code looks like this:

```
global $cssPath, $jsPath, $themePath, $theLayout;
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
echo $upload_dir['path'];
```

Any idea how I can use this properly? Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're either calling [`wp_upload_dir`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) too early, when it has not yet been included in the scope (which is nearly impossible), or calling it without WordPress being even loaded (highly probable).

If you're using some sort of `iframe` to provide `uploadify.php` directly then WordPress will not be available for it. Include `wp-load.php` to load up a WordPress environment before actually trying to use `wp_upload_dir`. Alternatively, and much better, include `uploadify.php` into the WordPress scope instead in your template or hook, whatever you are using to position to the upload form correctly.

Better yet, just use the code inside from the basic [demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) inside your template file directly without the need for a separate `uploadify.php`.